# I have a question on how to study maths, is MSE the right place for it?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have a question regarding how to study maths efficiently, and how the best study maths. Is this the best place for it?

Comment: Maybe, shading towards "no". But certainly make sure that you search first - there are already a lot of answers on how to study on the site.

Comment: Hope you find some good advice!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I basically agree with [JonathanZ supports MonicaC's comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35266/i-have-a-question-on-how-to-study-maths-is-mse-the-right-place-for-it#comment165839_35266) re: before possibly asking anything, you should first do a search. In particular, one tag to look at is [self-learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning), with it currently having $4224$ questions (including $256$ this year) and a description of:

> The process of studying mathematics without formal instruction. Don't use this tag just because you were self-studying when you came across the mathematical question you're asking; it is only for when the fact that you're self-studying is what your question is about.

Another tag I suggest checking is [learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning), with $576$ questions at this time (including $25$ from this year) and a description of:

> Questions about the process of learning mathematics, both inside and outside a formal environment, including learning strategies, recommendations for learning particular subjects, and studying habits.

Looking at the questions with these tags, especially the more recent ones, will also give you a better idea of what is, and is not, likely to be particularly acceptable here. Note that usage of these tags has been somewhat controversial, e.g., see [Do we need the (self-learning) tag?](/q/18969), [Learning tag - Opinion based](/q/17346), etc. However, both of these example posts are from over $5$ years ago and I believe the site is now, if anything, generally more strict with the sort of questions that are allowed. Thus, as the comment from "JonathanZ supports MonicaC" also indicates, you may have some difficulty writing a question that will be accepted on this site, e.g., will not be closed.

However, another SE site where questions such as what you're asking about may possibly be a better fit is [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) (MESE). Nonetheless, especially if you aren't familiar with this site, you should first read its [Help center](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help) information, especially the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page (since its second paragraph starts with "The community welcomes questions on teaching mathematics and the process of learning mathematics at all levels.", it seems your question(s), if appropriately focused, may be acceptable there).

Regarding the site's tags to check on, the first one I suggest is [self-learning](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning), with it having $149$ questions (including $15$ this year) and a description of:

> Questions about how someone learns on their his or her own, outside of traditional classroom environments.

Another tag you should investigate is [homework](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework), which has $72$ questions (with $2$ from this year) and a description of:

> For questions concerning homework, such as good problems for specific topics, amount and difficulty of homework, grading homework, cheating

Since you (like most people, I believe) may find it challenging (at least at times) to motivate yourself, the final tag I suggest going through is [student-motivation](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/student-motivation), with this currently listing $132$ questions (including $7$ from this year) and having a description of:

> For questions concerning the motivation of students and helping them to motivate for their study in general.

Regardless of the extent you find the information you're looking for (either in already existing questions/answers, or from the comments/answers to your own question(s)) on this site, on MESE, or on any other site(s), I wish you success with getting answers to your questions and with your future math study endeavors.

Answer (score 3):

No.  The best way to study Math is via a book and/or a class.  MathSE is useful when you encounter a problem that you can't solve.  MathSE is no substitute for books or classes.